# $f$ partial continuous $\Rightarrow$ $f$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$
Let $f\colon \R^n \to \R^m$. $f$ is *partial continuous* in $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \R^n$ iff $f_k\colon\R \to \R^m, x' \mapsto f(x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1},x',x_{k+1}\ldots,x_n)$ is continuous for all $1 \le k \le n$. My question: If $f$ is partial continuous in every $x \in \R^n$, does this imply the continuity of $f$?

---

*Additional information:* The inverse is clear to me. I can also construct an $f$ which is is partial continuous in a specific point (but not every point), but not continuous in this point (take $$f\colon \R^2\to \R,\quad f(x_1,x_2) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if $x_1x_2=0$}\\1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and $x=(0,0)$). So I wonder whether there exists a counterexample for the "global" case described above.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2810320/221811 is probably what you want.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$
@Chappers provided a link to a counterexample. Let $f\colon \R^2 \to \R$ by $$f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{x_1x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$$ and $x = (0,0)$. $f$ is obviously partial continuous in every point (just fix $x_1$ or $x_2$). But let $(a_k)_{k\ge0}$ via $a_k = \left(\frac{\sin(k)}k,\frac{\cos(k)}k\right)$. Then $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} a_k = (0,0) = x,$$ but $$\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} f(a_k) = \lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\sin(k)\cos(k) = \lim\limits_{k\to \infty} \frac12\sin(2k)$$ does not exist, so $f$ is not continuous. So the answer to my question is "wrong".

Comment: I think you set a very good example because you answered your own question. Many questions are de facto answered in form of comments, but never receive an official answer. For the user of StackExchange this has the negative effect that it is not visible in the list of questions that there is no need for action.

Comment: This $f$ is a very old counter-example in the topic of partial derivatives,  Define $f(0,0)=0.$ Then $\partial f/\partial x_i$ exists, and is continuous in $x_i$   (with the other co-ordinate fixed) for each $i\in \{1,2\},$ at every point in $\Bbb R^2,$ but  $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0.$